# How to pass a classname as an argument java

Tags: java, json

I have a method which is as shown below:

```
public class TestAssertionPickEvent {     
     PickEvent pickeventMq;
     PickEvent pickeventKafka;
     JsonNode messagefromKafka;
     JsonNode messagetoMQueue;

     @BeforeMethod
     public void before(){
       

        String filepath = "json/jsonfile.json";
        String jsonPayload = Utils.readFromResources(filepath);
        messagetoMQueue = objectMapper.readTree(jsonPayload);
       //Sending msg to activeMQ
        QueueSender qMessage = new QueueSender();
       qMessage.messageSentInQueue(props.getProperty("queuename"), jsonPayload, headers);
       log.info("Message sent to mq service");

       //Kafka consuming msg
        List<String> message = 
        KafkaMessageConsumer.consumeMessage(props.getProperty("topicname"));
        log.info("Message {}", message.size());

        //json to javaObject
        log.info("Creating  json to java object");
        for (String msg : message) {
           pickeventKafka=objectMapper.readValue(msg, PickEvent.class);
           log.info(pickeventKafka.toString());
           messagefromKafka = objectMapper.readTree(msg);
         }
       compareJson(messagefromKafka,messagetoMQueue);
   } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

I want to make this method to be generic, but I am not sure as to how to pass the class and JsonNode as an argument to a helper method. Is there anyway of doing it?

Comment: However, when it's annotated with `@BeforeMethod` you're not going to make it any more generic, but can can only call to another generic method, with alternating types of class.

Comment: @MartinZeitler thanks for the comment, will it be fine if you can please provide a code sample for this like should be: public void helper(Class<T> cls,...)?

Comment: @MartinZeitler Yes that is what I am trying to do, I want to call a generic method and I am not sure how to pass the class to the method, over here PickEvent.

Comment: It's difficult to tell by the example, if the annotation is even the correct one for the test case, but such generic method can return generic types, which have to be asserted with `instanceof`.